# Broken link "tagged question" on at "all sites" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com

The "Tagged question" link on the ["tagged question"](https://stackexchange.com/sites) page is broken and leads to `https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular>` instead of https://stackexchange.com/filters/popular

```
            <ul class="navMain">
                <li><a href="/" >Hot Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="/filters/popular>" >Tagged Questions</a></li>            
                <li><a href="/sites"  class=&quot;current&quot;>All Sites</a></li>

                <li><a href="/leagues" >Top Users</a></li>
            </ul>
```

An excess `>` is the problematic character.

Comment: Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oops, stray character. It's fixed now. Thanks for the report.